# Highlight Entire row of multiple blank cells without VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two columns such as the following:

```
col col2
A   
B    G
C    H 
D
E    J
```

And I would like to highlight the entire row where col2 has a blank cell. 
I have tried using conditional formatting>New Rule> isblank($B2)>highlight and F5>Special>blank>ok>ctrl>shift>leftarrow but both methods have not worked.

Comment: My bet is that you have a formula that returns a value or `""` and isblank() does not read those as blank.  Try `=$B2=""`

Comment: Perhaps I'm performing the steps wrong; I tried using that formula but it didn't work. I highlighted both columns> conditional formatting>New Rule>=$B2=" "> ok and nothing happened.

Comment: no space between the quotes; `""` not `" "`

Comment: hmm nothing was highlighted

Comment: see: http://imgur.com/a/edg7h

Comment: Interestingly, there were no highlight on my version. But once I copied and pasted those cells into a different workbook, they were highlighted. How strange.

Comment: Did you set a cell fill for the format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a different test. Excel differentiates between empty cells and cells with an empty string.

Test the length of the cell with `=Len($B2)=0` to catch cells with no value, even if that "blank" is created with a formula like `=if(TRUE,"A","")`.

Of course, if you use a space between the "" signs, then Len(B2) will return a 1.

Edit: added a screenshot. Also, you need to define a format. If you don't, nothing will be highlighted.

[image]

Comment: I did so and got the correct TRUE/FALSES. Then I applied the conditional formatting and still didn't get the highlights I wanted.

Comment: 'scuse me, but my crystal ball is broken. You will need to actually describe to me what you see on your screen. Most likely your referencing is off or you don't apply to the correct range.

Comment: I added a screenshot with the formula and the whole setup. If you don't get it to work check your formula and the "Applies" to range.

Comment: What I see on my screen is

Comment: You can't add screenshots to comments. Check your formula. Add a format. Check what it applies to. If you want to share a screenshot, edit your question, put a link to the screenshot there (you don't have sufficient reputation to post a screenshot, so just post a link) and we can pick it up. Post a comment when you've done that.

Comment: are FALSE beside B, G / C, H/ E, J. TRUES beside A,"" /D,""  based on my data set above. Once I applied the conditional formatting, nothing was highlighted and the data set looked exactly as it did before. Now interestingly, when I copied and pasted the data set in a different worksheet, all the highlights showed up, I don't know why that happened but I'm going to try to figure it out. Thanks for pasting such a clear explanation.

Comment: I was wondering, why might everything be highlighted after I applied the formula?

Answer (score 0):

Make a name Flag that shows if the cell should be highlighted.

1. Select a cell on the second row

Go into the name manager (located on formula ribbon)

2. Make a new name, Flag

   - Enter =ISBLANK($B2) in the refers section at the bottom

For verification, you can test it out in a few empty cells to the right by entering =Flag. It should be 'true' if the b cell is blank, else 'false'

3. Go into conditional format

   - choose formula
   - =flag
   - set what you want it to look like if the B cell is empty